# close/hide keyboard on tap outside keyboard in phone gap

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

i want to hide keyboard on tap event other than keyboard i.e. if i click outside keyboard or on button it should hide. I am using phonegap / cordova with jquery mobile.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this.
I had issue with closing keyboard.
I added code as 
 `$("#id_of_textbox").blur();` 
in tap event on all buttons wherever possible on that screen.